# Can't enroll device. Error 500

Tags: java, wso2, iot, wso2-iot

I just installed ***WSO2 iotserver 3.1.0*** . 
When i try to enroll a device (Android) i get :

> Enrollment failed
>
> Please contact administrator. Code : 500
>
> Error : java.io.EOFException

I have yet to figure out the issue.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This could happen due to multiple issues.

1. If you are using HTTPS instead of HTTP without installing the certificates to the android agent (For this you will have to compile the Android agent. [More information](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Configuring+Android+for+HTTPS+Communication)). When you are enrolling, give the server address as {IP}:8280 and username/password as admin/admin.
2. If the server is not accessible by the device. Please make sure that device is in a network which has access to the server.
3. Ports not being opened.(8243, 8280, 9443, 9763)
4. Due to a configuration error.

The best solution is to run the change-ip.sh script to set up the server. [More information](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Configuring+the+IP+or+Hostname#ConfiguringtheIPorHostname-ConfiguringtheIPorhostnameusingthescript)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
For some reason, i have a different error message now: 
`Enrollment failed

Please contact administrator. Code : 500
Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshakefailed.`

Seems pretty clear now that it is linked to the SSL certificate. But
1- I tried to follow the link, stuck on the 2nd part as i can't find a way to update the SDK from command line. I don't have a desktop environment installed on my server so no GUI for me.
3- I use a default Debian image, so no ports restriction.

I actually used the change-ip.sh script to get to this point

Comment: Is there a simple way to force using HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Comment: Use 8280 port when connecting the device. Please look these videos

Comment: Thanks for the video, that's exactly what i did, but i still get the same error.
this is driving me crazy. I used the change-ip.sh script again but no luck

Comment: If you use 8280 port, you should not get the SSL handshake issue. Because it is HTTP (non-secure) port.

Comment: Then there is something seriously wrong with my setup, because this is the exact issue i have. I used the 8280 port with both the ip address and the full hostname of my server, same error in both cases.
Maybe i'll try setting up the whole thing from scratch

Comment: I've noticed something weird, when i start the broker server, i get the following :

`[2017-10-15 20:08:43,583] [IoT-Broker]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://IPADDRESS:9446/carbon/`

Shouldn't it show the server hostname and domain instead of the ip address?

Comment: That is correct if you have run the change-ip.sh script.

Comment: Just to let you know, it's actually working.
For some reason my HTC device will not register.
I tried with my Note 4 and it register. Also register correctly with a LG G Flex. I'll try more devices.
Do you have any idea why i do get the message above when i run the broker server?

Comment: I am not sure why the HTC phone has an issue with device registration. Please note that Android agent supports above 4.2 (JellyBeans).

Comment: Found out the reason : i had an old version of the android agent also installed,( from EMM 2.2.0 if i remember correctly). I uninstalled that one, restarted the device and could register it.
Besides that specific phone location feature not working, everything works quite good now. Another question: when i ring a device or send a message, it can take up to 5 minutes for the device to receive that message, is that a normal behavior? 
I also have another issue : i can't access the management console at hostname:9763/carbon or hostname:9443/carbon.
I have a blank white page.

Comment: On hostname:9446/carbon, i have the server security warning message then get an Error 403 - Forbidden

Comment: There is a known issue about the "carbon" console. I hope you have started all 3 servers (broker, analytics, and iot-core) or at least 2 of them. If yes, can you restart only the iot-core server and it will fix the "carbon" console issue for iot-core. To make sure that you can log in to carbon console of the iot-core server, start that server at last after other two servers (broker and analytics) started.

Comment: "hostname:9446" is used by the broker and we have disabled the carbon console access intentionally

Answer (score 0):

- **Do it like below :**

  do not give your server ip address `(112.234.34.888)` or the  IP address with 9443 port like `(112.234.34.888:9443)`.

  - **STEP 1** : Tap on Continue

[image]

- **STEP 2** : tap on skip and go to enrollment

[image]

- **STEP 3** : enter your server IP address with the port **8280**. make sure port 8280 is opened in your server.

[image]

- **FINAL STEP** : Enter the credentials like below. then your are good to go.

[image]